# Type scaffolding / commutative composition

Tags: haskell

I have 3 types : `Task` (a unit of work), `Estimate` (a time period) and `User`.

In my app, I'd like to "decorate" my `Task`s to make `EstimedTask` (that could be sum-ed), `AssignedTask` (to be sorted) and `AssignedEstimatedTask` (that are both and on which I can apply a Gantt algorithm)

My first try is to implement them with tuples :

```
EstimatedTask :: (Task, Estimate)
AssignedTask :: (Task, User)
AssignedEstimatedTask :: (Task, Estimate, User)
```

but then if I want to construct an `AET` I have to define 3 constructors

```
T -> E -> U -> AET
(T, E) -> U -> AET
(T, U) -> E -> AET
```

As I intend to decorate even more, I'm afraid the number of constructor will explode.

Is there a smart way to do that ?
In particular, is there a prefered method to make sub-constructor commutative (such that `assign . estimate $ task == estimate . assign $ task` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define `data Controlled :: Type -> Bool -> Type` such that `Controlled t False` is a singleton type (like `()`, no information) and `Controlled t True` is a copy of `t`:

```
data Controlled :: Type -> Bool -> Type where
    Exists :: a -> Controlled a True
    NonExist :: Controlled a False
```

Then define a "full" type representing everything you can have, with `Controlled` slots:

```
data AssignedEstimatedTask' :: Bool -> Bool -> Type where
    AssignedEstimatedTask ::
        { getTask :: Task
        , taskUser :: Controlled User a
        , taskEstimate :: Controlled Estimate b } ->
        AssignedEstimatedTask' a b
```

Fill in a bunch of synonyms:

```
-- naming the types is exponential!
type JustTask = AssignedEstimatedTask' False False
type AssignedTask = AssignedEstimatedTask' True False
type EstimatedTask = AssignedEstimatedTask' False True
type AssignedEstimatedTask = AssignedEstimatedTask' True True

justTask :: Task -> JustTask
justTask t = AssignedEstimatedTask t NonExist NonExist
```

And now you can add things to a task by using record updates, which are tracked at compile-time:

```
jTask :: JustTask
aTask :: AssignedTask
eTask :: EstimatedTask
aeTask, eaTask :: AssignedEstimatedTask
-- ofc, all of ^ could have been inferred
jTask = justTask someTask
aTask = jTask { taskUser = Exists someUser }
eTask = jTask { taskEstimate = Exists someEstimate }
aeTask = aTask { taskEstimate = Exists someEstimate }
eaTask = eTask { taskUser = Exists someUser }
-- aeTask == eaTask
```

[Working example](https://repl.it/repls/UnlinedJovialMemoryallocator)

If you really want to extract the record updates as functions, they look like this

```
assignTask :: User -> AssignedEstimatedTask' a e -> AssignedEstimatedTask' True e
assignTask u t = t { taskUser = Exists u }
estimateTask :: Estimate -> AssignedEstimatedTask' a e -> AssignedEstimatedTask' a True
estimateTask e t = t { taskEstimate = Exists e }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the time taken to write it. It kind of saddens me to have to create a God type that knows everything, but I see that it is the easiest (only ?) way to get commutativity.

Comment: @smwhr This is probably the easiest (i.e. it fits understandably into one answer), but not the only. This problem is basically the "extensible record problem" and there are tons of libraries that try to solve it, all slightly differently.

Comment: With that term in mind I'm beginning my quest on Google !